# Equilibrium constant for the thermal dissociation of phosphorus pentachloride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, equilibrium

> Thermal decomposition of $\ce{PCl5}$ is studied in a closed vessel. Partial pressure of $\ce{PCl5}$ in gaseous equilibrium mixture is $\pu{1 atm}.$ $\pu{50 \%}$ $\ce{PCl5}$ dissociates. Find equilibrium constant.

I am aware of the formula of equilibrium constant, but I am finding difficult determining concentration of reactants and products from partial pressure and $\pu{50 \%}$ dissociation.

I know the formula

$$K_c = \frac{[\ce{PCl3}][\ce{Cl2}]}{[\ce{PCl5}]},$$

but how to calculate the concentration?

Comment: In the future, please try to come up with meaningful titles and avoid randomly using math mode. Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. As for the question itself, I suggest to start with writing down balanced chemical equation and observe the relation between concentrations from there.

Comment: **HINT** For gases there are two equilibrium constants, $K_\mathrm{p}$ and $K_\mathrm{c}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note the equation as follows: $$\ce{PCl5 <=> Cl2 + PCl3}$$

You may begin with an ICE table showing the initial and final pressures of the gases.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
 & \ce{PCl5}  & \ce{PCl3} &\ce{Cl2} \\ \hline
\text{Initial} & 2 & 0&0 \\ \hline
\text{Change} & -1 & +1 & +1 \\\hline
\text{Equilibrium} & 1 & 1 &1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Then it is a simple matter to find $K_p$ with the equation $$K_p = \frac{[\ce{P_{PCl_3}}][\ce{P_{Cl_2}}]}{[\ce{P_{PCl_5}}]}$$

If you would like $K_c$ you would need the ideal gas law ($PV=nRT$) but I doubt that is what your question requires.